# Argument Placeholder, or other convention, in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

**Question Context:**
I'm writing documentation for an API, including something like a quick-start guide. The guide has some blocks of code which are intended to be written so they can be copied by the developer. Then the developer can insert use-case specific things, like certain function arguments, in their code.

**Primary Objective:**
I'd like the experience for the developer of using the copied code examples with placeholders to be as fast and easy as possible. I'd like it to be immediately visible after pasting the code into the developer's code that the argument(s) must be inserted, and the process of doing so to be as quick as possible. Placeholders as in the following examples are not necessary. Ease of understanding and speed of implementation for the developer is the objective.

**Existing Examples:**
For example, in Xcode a piece of code can be marked as an argument placeholder with the notation `<#PlaceholderText#>`. By convention the placeholder text is the type of the value which is to be inserted. When it is pasted in the editor, the placeholder is then highlighted, and can be selected by tapping tab. So         `apiExampleFunction(name: <#String#> /* thing one's name */, height: <#Int#> /* thing one's height */)` can be filled in by typing only tab "thing one" tab "2" and would look like this in the editor:

[image: Argument Placeholder example in Xcode]

IntelliJ appears to have a [similar parameter placeholder feature](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010100620/comments/360002483340)

**Note:** In part my extensive googling has been thwarted considerably by lots of other things named placeholder. I'm sorry if this is simple and well known, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean the [live templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html) feature?

Comment: @AndrewT., If parameterized templates (a sub feature of live templates) can be copied from a website and pasted into Android Studio, then yes. Otherwise the parameterized templates feature is close. I have a web page with code text which will be copied by the developer. When the developer pastes the code into Android Studio it would be great if it could have the "variables … replaced by input fields" described by IntelliJ which occurs with parameterized templates in IntelliJ IDEA, and as occurs in Xcode when text, as in the example shown in my question, is pasted into Xcode's text editor.

Comment: Android Studio is based completely on IntelliJ IDEA, but if that's not what you want, then I'm not sure if it's even possible. At least, I've never heard of such a feature on Android Studio/IntelliJ IDEA. What you linked for IntelliJ IDEA is about code auto-completion based on installed libraries, not copy-pasting.